# Trying to Convert a Java JNA call to C# DLL Call

Tags: java, c#, c++, dll

I have a Java DLL call through JNA, now i'm trying to convert it to C#...
I've been trying to convert the structure call to C# and i think i'm making it work little by little until i get to this Codes..

Original Call:

```
bool GetQuotes(int, double*, double*)
```

JNa Converted Call:

```
byte GetQuotes(int BusConnectorID, DoubleBuffer Buf1, DoubleBuffer Buf2);
byte GetQuotes(int BusConnectorID, DoubleByReference Buf1, DoubleByReference Buf2);
```

And, these calls also looks confusing to me, even though i can convert char* to Pointer name in C#

Original Codes:

```
int CreateConnection(int, char*)
bool GetConnectionName(int, BYTE, char[256])
char GetConnectionsCount(int)
DWORD GetDataSize(int)
```

JNA Converted Codes:

```
@deprecated
int CreateConnection(int BusConnectorID, ByteBuffer ConnectionName);
int CreateConnection(int BusConnectorID, Pointer ConnectionName);
@Deprecated 
byte GetConnectionName(int BusConnectorID, byte ConnectionNumber, Pointer ConnectionName);
byte GetConnectionsCount(int BusConnectorID);
byte GetConnectionName(int BusConnectorID, byte ConnectionNumber, ByteBuffer ConnectionName);
}
byte GetConnectionName(int BusConnectorID, byte ConnectionNumber, Pointer ConnectionName);
int GetDataSize(int BusConnectorID);
```

I'm really confused about converting this to C# call as there is none of the equivalent i could see online...

The Codes and the JNA/Java Converted Codes are listed respectively..

**I want to make them work on C# code..**

I'm using this to call the DLL code in C#.

```
[DllImport("ipclib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = false)]
    public static extern bool Functions(int types);
```

Thanks for Taking your time..